# ENS Paris preparation

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, advice

Good morning everyone, I'm a french student who wants to pass the contest of ENS Ulm I need specific problems and exercises, I hope someone would help me here... I know there are many french student in this forum. 
Let's start with this difficult oral which was given in ENS Paris:

> What is the dimension of vector space of symmetric polynomials with $k$ variables and degree at most $n$ ?

I've seen this problem in this forum but no convincing answer were given. Thanks for your help, I'll be so much thankful.

Comment: The monomials $x_1^{d_1} \cdots x_k^{d_k}$ (where $d_j \ge 0$ and $d_1 + \cdots + d_k \le n$) can appear in any polynomial of degree $\le n$, but for symmetric polynomials, the coefficients for $x_1^{d_1} \cdots x_k^{d_k}$ and $x_1^{d'_1} \cdots x_k^{d'_k}$ must be the same if $(d_1, \ldots, d_k)$ is a permutation of $(d'_1, \ldots, d'_k)$.
Thus, the dimension of the vector space is the number of tuples $(d_1, \ldots, d_k)$ such that $d_j \ge 0$ and $d_1 + \cdots + d_k \le n$, and, say, $d_1 \ge d_2 \ge \cdots \ge d_k$. I'm not sure how to deal with this combinatorics problem.